# How to link sources from SVN to be analysed with SonarQube

Tags: svn, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am working on a project for which I would want to perform quality analysis. I have heard good things about `SonarQube` and wanted to try it. I have the following setup:

`SonarQube` is installed along with Sonar Runner for Java on a server. It is configured and ready to go. I have my code residing locally on my machine and remotely on a `SVN` server distinct from the `SonarQube` host server.

I am using Eclipse and have installed Sonar Eclipse. I would want to proceed with scheduled quality analysis on the server and work locally with previews using Sonar Eclipse. At the moment, my biggest problem is how to get my source files analysed by the Sonar Runner.

As far as I read in the documentation, I would need to somehow get my code into the respective folder in the `SonarQube` Project folder, along with a configuration file. Is there no was to link the project to the remote source files?

Looking at some of the [documentation on links](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-CustomizingLinks) it would seem that this is possible. Yet I do not understand the differences between, for example, `Sources` and `Developer connections`.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube will not fetch the source code by itself, the Project Links section is only meant for documentation.

The easiest way to have the source code from your repository analyzed periodically is to schedule analysis using a dedicated tool - e.g cron task, Windows scheduled task or even better, continuous integration server.

For instance, you can setup a Jenkins job to fetch source code from your SVN repository, build it, run automated tests and finally launch SonarQube Runner.

Comment: I don't want to fetch the source code, I want to tell it where it can find it. That location happens to be my SVN server. The (quite scarce I might add) documentation does not specify where the project folder must reside!

Comment: Please read my first sentence: it will not fetch the source code by itself from your SVN repository.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know it won't fetch source code and, as I said, it is not what I want to do. The code is to remain where it is. I want to set a remote source folder for SonarQube to work on.

Comment: AFAIK SonarQune runner can only work on a local directory, so if you want to work with a remote one, you will want to have it appear as a local one (e.g assign it a drive letter if using Windows or through NFS/CIFS if using a POSIX OS).

Comment: Thank you! While inconvenient this might work. Alternatively I guess I could rely on "on-the-fly" analysis using the Eclipse plug-in. Do you know if that would be a viable option?

Comment: The analysis performed by the Eclipse plugin is in preview mode, it does not persist anything to the SQ server. So it might prove useful as a quick response mechanism for developers, but it will not replace a standard analysis if you want to manage the evolution of your project's quality.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is

- Have SVN (client part) on SonarQube host
- Create WC of you project on SonarQube host
- On demand update SonarQube's Working Copy to actual HEAD and perform analysis (you may also to want to store results in the repository /somehow separately from code/ and in this case results can be stored in WC and commited to repository)

For Git workflow will differ only slightly: you have to have Git, clone repo (once), pull on demand, commit results to local repo but never push to upstream

**Edit:**

As [mentioned by Patroklos Papapetrou](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/simple-integration-of-sonarQube-with-just-svn-tp5017436p5017442.html)

> All SonarQube clients ( sonar-runner, maven plugin etc. ) **require**
>   that source code is already **available in the machine** you're
>   running the analysis

thus, if you don't want (can't have) SVN WC on SonarQube *and* want analysis after each commit you have only one choice:

- In post-commit hook at Subversion server side perform

  - Export repository (trunk) tree into some local temporary folder
  - Transfer tree (using any available for you method /ssh, ftp, rsync/)  to SonarQube's host directory (freed from of the previous analysis sources), there sonar-runner can be used

Comment: It is not possible to have both SVN and SonarQube on the same host. Updating files on demand is also something I would not want to do. I want to commit my changes and then schedule an analysis.

Comment: Read http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/simple-integration-of-sonarQube-with-just-svn-tp5017436p5017442.html

Comment: Exactly, I read that multiple times today. I don't want to integrate anything. My question is, how can I link the source code to my repository? As the repository gets updated by each commit, running the analyser would work just fine as any SCM business should be transparent.